# php Date Calculation loop?

Tags: php, date

I have a date calculation loop but I don't know how to code to achieve right output

here are my current code

```
//This code is showing all dates from range of date

$year1 = '2011';
$month1 = '10';
$day1 = '17';

$day1 = $day1 + 1;

$year2 = '2012';
$month2 = '03';
$day2 = '17';

$start_date = "$year1-$month1-$day1";
echo "Start Date = $start_date ";
$end_date = "$year2-$month2-$day2";
echo "End Date = $end_date ";

$date = mktime(0,0,0,$month1,$day1,$year1); //Gets Unix timestamp START DATE
$date1 = mktime(0,0,0,$month2,$day2,$year2); //Gets Unix timestamp END DATE
$difference = $date1-$date; //Calcuates Difference
$daysago = floor($difference /60/60/24); //Calculates Days Old


$i = 0;
while ($i <= $daysago +1) {
if ($i != 0) { $date = $date + 86400; }
else { $date = $date - 86400; }
$today = date('Y-m-d',$date);
//echo "$today ";

$yy = date('Y',$date);
$mm = date('m',$date);
$dd = date('d',$date);

echo "$mm-$dd-$yy <br/>";
$i++;
}
```

Above code shows

10-18-2011
10-19-2011
10-20-2011
10-21-2011
10-22-2011
10-23-2011
10-24-2011
10-25-2011
10-26-2011
10-27-2011
10-28-2011
10-29-2011
10-30-2011
10-31-2011
11-01-2011
11-02-2011
11-03-2011
11-04-2011
11-05-2011
 .
 .
so on
03-17-2012

and I wanting to get output from particular month day like show below code

```
11-17-2011
12-17-2011
01-17-2012
02-17-2012
03-17-2012
```

Comment: This is not a 'Write my code please' kinda site. You will have to do some effort in order to get others to respond with code.

Comment: @Jeffrey my apologies I edited and add my current code that I have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of giving your user a text field for the date, you should give them something more foolproof, like three dropdowns, each with month, day, and year:

```
<select id='month' name='month'>
<option value='01'>Jan</option>
<option value='02'>Feb</option>
etc...
</select>
<select id='day' name='day'>
<option value='01'>01</option>
<option value='02'>02</option>
etc...
```

Your php to which the form is submitted:

```
$month = $_POST['month'];
$day = $_POST['day'];
$year = $_POST['year'];
$no_dates = $POST['no_dates']; //the number of dates

$i = 0;
while ($i < $no_dates){
date = mktime(0,0,0,$month+$i,$day,$year)
print date('Y-m-d', $date)."<br/>";
$i = $i + 1;
}
```

Comment: this one is much closer that I wanted to have :) thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

The following code will produce the output you mentioned:

```
$date1 = strtotime("2011-10-17");
$date2 = strtotime("2012-03-17");
$time = 0;
for($i = 0; ($time = strtotime("+$i month", $date1)) <= $date2; $i++) {
    echo date("m-d-Y\n", $time);
}
```

Output:

```
10-17-2011
11-17-2011
12-17-2011
01-17-2012
02-17-2012
03-17-2012
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?php
$dateMonthYearArr = array();
$fromDateTS = mktime(0,0,0,10,17,2011);
$toDateTS = mktime(0,0,0,3,17,2012);

for ($currentDateTS = $fromDateTS; $currentDateTS <= $toDateTS; $currentDateTS += (60 * 60 * 24)) {
    if (date('d',$currentDateTS)==17){
       $dateMonthYearArr[] = date('Y-m-d',$currentDateTS);
    }
}

echo  '<pre>';
print_r($dateMonthYearArr);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: this one work perfectly thank you so much :)